# Reading document in Lucene

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

My indexed document in Lucene has got multiple cities assigned to it...ie.
doc.Add(new Field("city", city1.Trim(), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.TOKENIZED));
doc.Add(new Field("city", city2.Trim(), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.TOKENIZED));
etc

how do i iterate thru them and read the values after executing the Lucene search query?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call [Document.getValues](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_4_1/api/core/org/apache/lucene/document/Document.html) for stored fields with multiple values.